# A RenderFlex overflowed by 61 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter

how to fix this error It's about the layout size. It says the bottom is over 61 pixels. But try wrapping SizeBox with Container and put a height to it, the height doesn't move at all some lines There's a some lines put height so it moves to the orange frame. Which is no more than the orange frame, I don't know which line to change. Try to put SingleChildScrollView and set scrollDirection: Axis.vertical. It's a disaster, but the layout doesn't.

```
class PlaceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlaceCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.travelSport,
    this.isFullCard = false,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TravelSpot travelSport;
  final bool isFullCard;
  final GestureTapCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final kDefualtShadow = BoxShadow(
      offset: const Offset(5, 5),
      blurRadius: 10,
      color: const Color(0xFFE9E9E9).withOpacity(0.56),
    );

    return //SingleChildScrollView(
        //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        //child:
        SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1.9,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                ),
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(travelSport.image), fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 150,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(
              20,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              boxShadow: [kDefualtShadow],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  travelSport.name,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
                if (isFullCard)
                  Text(
                    travelSport.date.day.toString(),
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .headlineMedium!
                        .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                if (isFullCard)
                  Text(
                    DateFormat.MMMM().format(travelSport.date) +
                        " " +
                        travelSport.date.year.toString(),
                  ),
                VerticalSpacing(of: 10),
                Travelers(
                  users: travelSport.users,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show Travelers widget code?

Comment: It's not about Travelers, it's about AspectRatio. aspectRatio: 1.9 above straight column

Comment: I run your code except Travelers and its work fine..